# No Firebase tab under tools, can't add Firebase to the project

Tags: android-studio, firebase

[NO FIREBASE TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrTTv.png)

I'm trying to add Firebase to my Android app, but I can't find the Firebase tab under the Tools tab .

What i've tried so far is :

[image]

1. I updated my Google repository to version 58
2. I made sure that I'm using Android newer than 4.0
3. Searched for the Firebase plugins but couldn't find any

Here are screenshots

Comment: do you have android-studio 3.0?

Comment: No my version is 2.1 , is the problem of the firebase version realted problem ?

Comment: That's new info to me . I'll update it  , Thanks a lot.

Comment: my mistake i doubled checked in the docs you should be able to find it in version 2.2 and higher

Comment: yes , i updated it and it works . Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google added firebase in Android Studio after v2.2+. You can upgrade your Android Studio to get firebase support built-in.